# renderscript rsMatrixMultiply function

Tags: android, renderscript

I am developing an OpenGL ES 2.0 android application, by porting the code from an renderscript created application. In renderscript this function is used:

```
float4 rsMatrixMultiply(rs_matrix4x4 *m, float3 in);
```

Does anyone knows what exactly this function does and how it is implemented, because I need to use it in my OpenGL application using Java.

Comment: Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html . You may have to do some manual matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

This does standard matrix multiplication between the matrix 'm' and the vector 'in'.  The result is placed back in 'm'.  In order to multiply the 4x4 matrix with a vector of size 3, this function behaves as if the vector were float4 with a value of 1 for the w dimension.

For the documentation around this function, take a look here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/renderscript/rs__matrix_8rsh.html

Below is the actual code from rs_core.c of the AOSP:

```
extern float4 __attribute__((overloadable))
rsMatrixMultiply(const rs_matrix4x4 *m, float3 in) {
    float4 ret;
    ret.x = (m->m[0] * in.x) + (m->m[4] * in.y) + (m->m[8] * in.z) + m->m[12];
    ret.y = (m->m[1] * in.x) + (m->m[5] * in.y) + (m->m[9] * in.z) + m->m[13];
    ret.z = (m->m[2] * in.x) + (m->m[6] * in.y) + (m->m[10] * in.z) + m->m[14];
    ret.w = (m->m[3] * in.x) + (m->m[7] * in.y) + (m->m[11] * in.z) + m->m[15];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. but from this link I can't see the code that explains exactly what this function does. because as u can see, it multiplys a 4x4 matrix with **float3** vector. From basic math I know  that you can multiply 4x4 matrix by float4 vector. In this case it's some kind of overloaded function that does different caluclation.

Comment: @Sandra, the function assumes a value of 1 for the vector's w value.  I've edited my response.

Comment: @spatulamania so could this be used in order to rotate images ? if so, how?

Comment: @spatulamania - +1.  Thank you.  The Renderscript API is very vague on how this computation is performed.  Thanks for the link to the AOSP!